# Woocommerce - How can I transfer variation data to a function for a live display of the price calculation formula on the single product page?

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, product-variations

I've already spent a few days on this, but I'm still pretty new to javascript, so I've been struggling with getting this to work.
For a client, I need to display the entire price calculation formula live on the single product page when the user selects a different variation of the product from the dropdown and/or when a different product length is entered (number field). In order to get the variation price, I've been using this:

```
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    var preis_variation = variation.display_regular_price;
    var gewicht_variation = variation.weight;
} );
```

My issue is that I'm unable to access these two variables in the function that follows. I also tried setting global variables at the beginning, but these are not updated with the above code.

This is the full code:

```
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    var preis_variation = 0;
    var gewicht_variation = 0;
    
    window.onload = function () {
                // initiate function grundkosten on dropdown change
        document.getElementById("pa_durchmesser").addEventListener('change', grundkosten);
                // initiate function grundkosten on number field change
        document.getElementById("wck_laenge").addEventListener('change', grundkosten);

               // get variation price and weight
        $( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
            var preis_variation = variation.display_regular_price;
            var gewicht_variation = variation.weight;
        } );
        
                // get additional information and display the calculation within a given html structure
        function grundkosten() {
            var uebertrag_laenge = document.getElementById("wck_laenge").value;
            document.getElementById("facon").innerHTML = preis_variation;
            document.getElementById("kosten_laenge").innerHTML = uebertrag_laenge;
            document.getElementById("total_grundkosten").innerHTML = uebertrag_laenge * 0.50;
            
            var uebertrag_goldpreis = document.getElementById("gold_preis_hidden").value;
            document.getElementById("goldpreis_laenge").innerHTML = uebertrag_laenge;
            document.getElementById("gewicht").innerHTML = gewicht_variation;
            document.getElementById("goldpreis_aktuell").innerHTML = uebertrag_goldpreis;
            document.getElementById("total_goldpreis").innerHTML = uebertrag_laenge * uebertrag_goldpreis;  
        }
    }
} );
</script>
```

I tried moving this block

```
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    var preis_variation = variation.display_regular_price;
    var gewicht_variation = variation.weight;
} );
```

into the function grundkosten hoping to get access to the variables, but no change. The function grundkosten still does not allow access to preis_variation and gewicht_variation.

I would greatly appreciate some help in how I can transfer the variables to the function grundkosten. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Looking at your code (jQuery onload bit), it would seem that it's a scoping issue - you can remove the `var` keyword from `preis_variation` and `gewicht_variation` - there's no need to re-declare them, you have already declared them before, and you're just setting their value now. Check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/mw7kurto/) to better understand what's happening - be sure to open the console, to monitor the logs, and what happens when you click on the button in the example.

Comment: @FiddlingAway: Thanks a lot, this did the trick! I now have another issue, though. For some reason - even when moving it into the function grundkosten - this code         $( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
            var preis_variation = variation.display_regular_price;
            var gewicht_variation = variation.weight;
        } ); runs only after the rest of function grundkosten. This results in the data not being updated correctly (always one step too late). Do you have any idea on how to force this to execute first?

Comment: That might be because the `.on` event handler has been moved to be inside the `grundkosten` function, and is being constantly attached to the `.single_variation_wrap` element. To be sure if that's the case, add a `console.log("triggered")` inside the ` $( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on('show_variation', ....) `, and check the console if there is an increasing number of logs when you call `grundkosten()`. If that's the case, you should see it displayed once, twice, three times, four times, etc, for every subsequent calling of `grundkosten()`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway: This is correct. When inside grundkosten(), it displays x times after the x-th function call. When moving it back out of grundkosten(), it displays only once after every function call. So far so good, but I'm still getting the data update too late. I added a console.log "First" within the .single_variation_wrap element and a console.log "Second" at the beginning of grundkosten(). "Second" always triggers first, which creates the issue. I now have the following sequence in the console: Second, triggered, First with "triggered" being just before "First" in the code.

Comment: Do you need to have the event handler inside your `grundkosten` function? How is the `show_variation` event triggered? Can you move the call to the `grundkosten` inside that event handler (an inverse solution to what you were trying to do)? It would do a recalculation on every triggering of `show_variation`, and you might not want that.

Comment: @FiddlingAway: No, I don't need to have the event handler in grundkosten(), I only tried different options. The show_variation event gets triggered every time a new product variation (e.g. t-shirt size) gets selected from a dropdown. I now moved the call to grundkosten() to within the .single_variation_wrap element, but this does not seem to work as it no longer triggers the function. What you mentioned is exactly what I need to happen: every time a different variation is selected from the dropdown, the price formula needs to recalculate as there is a different price for each variation.

Comment: So, doing something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/nf14urxc/) isn't working (look for the JS comment `change starts here`)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway: This works perfectly now, I misunderstood your previous message. Thank you so much for your help, you saved my week :-)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above is to amend this portion of the code as follows:

```
    // get variation price and weight
    $( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
        preis_variation = variation.display_regular_price;
        gewicht_variation = variation.weight;
        
        grundkosten();
    } );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).